# How do I sort a list of files and concatenate the contents in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, sed, concatenation

This works:

```
find . -name "*.1" -print0 | xargs -0 cat > list.txt
```

But when I try to sort the the filenames, remove the newline the list of filenames that are piped to cat look identical to the previous but sorted:

```
find . -name "*.1" | sort | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' | xargs -0 cat > list.txt
```

However cat returns this error:

```
: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xargs statement is expecting null terminated entries.

```
find . -name '*.1' | sort | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs cat > list.txt
```

If your filenames or directories have spaces, then yes, use the null terminated way.

Answer (score 1):

Just use nul terminators all the way:

```
find . -name "*.1" -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 cat > list.txt
```

Your attempt failed because you just deleted all line feeds (effectively concatenating all filenames). This renders the same way in a terminal as NUL-separated filenames, but doesn't work the same way.